# Data in a processing screen disappears

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom processing page.  The main DAC of the data view is **ARRegister**, but there is the data view delegate.  Both the view & delegate join **ARCashSale** & **ARInvoice** to the main DAC, The reason for this is...some records are cash sales, and others are invoices, overdue charges, ect.  A few grid columns are included, which displays data specific to a cash sale.  I invoke a static method in my process graph to assign the process delegate.  The method runs with no errors.

In the data view delegate, I check the doc type for each record returned from the BQL.
If cash sale, then 
`yield return new PXResult<ARRegister, ARCashSale>(register, cashsale)`
ELSE
`yield return new PXResult<ARRegister>(register)`

The reason for the delegate is to check some other conditions which cannot be determined using standard BQL.  I notice the data in the column specific to a cash sale disappears after the user selects 'Process All'.  I am unable to determine the reason. Checking to see if others have experienced this.

**DataView**

```
public PXProcessingJoin<ARRegister,
        LeftJoin<cs.ARCashSale, On<ARRegister.docType, Equal<cs.ARCashSale.docType>, And<ARRegister.refNbr, Equal<cs.ARCashSale.refNbr>>>,
        LeftJoin<ARInvoice, On<ARRegister.docType, Equal<ARInvoice.docType>, And<ARRegister.refNbr, Equal<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>,
            InnerJoin<Customer,On<ARRegister.customerID,Equal<Customer.bAccountID>>>>>,
        Where2<Where<ARRegister.released, Equal<True>, And<ARRegister.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>,
            And<Where<Customer.finChargeApply,Equal<True>>>>> Registers;
```

Comment: I too have this similar issue, after they click process button the information in joined columns are disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I had a similar issue.

You need to add a boolean field named "Selected" to DACs you want to process.

The way I solved it was using a local DAC.
You can make it inherit from ARRegister and just add the required field.

In my case I used PXProjection, inherited from the main DAC and added the fields I needed from the joined DACs. Note that you need to add the `BqlField = typeof(DAC.field)` property to the type attribute of these fields to map them to the correct DAC.

Then in the `PXProcessing` view you just use your local DAC.

Also, it is very useful to try the Request Profiler screen (SM205070) when troubleshooting BQL.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in processing screens sub DAC (other than Main DAC in view), filed values will not persist once the process completed.

In this case, the PXProjection will help us to persist the values even after completion of the process for the rows/records in processing screens.

Please find the sample Projection View and DAC below.

```
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<SOShipment, InnerJoin<SOOrderShipment,
                                            On<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>,
                                            And<SOShipment.status, Equal<SOShipmentStatus.confirmed>>>,
                                            InnerJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrderShipment.orderType, Equal<SOOrder.orderType>,
                                            And<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>>))]


Projection DAC:

    [Serializable]
public class ProjectionShipmentDAC : IBqlTable
{
       #region Selected
       public abstract class selected : IBqlField
       {
       }
       protected bool? _Selected = false;
       [PXBool]
       [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
       public virtual bool? Selected
       {
           get
           {
               return _Selected;
           }
           set
           {
               _Selected = value;
           }
       }
       #endregion

       #region Status
       [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, BqlField = typeof(SOShipment.status))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
       [SOShipmentStatus.List()]
       public virtual string Status { get; set; }
       public abstract class status : IBqlField { }
       #endregion

        #region ShipmentNbr
       [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(SOShipment.shipmentNbr))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipment Nbr.")]
       public virtual string ShipmentNbr { get; set; }
       public abstract class shipmentNbr : IBqlField { }
       #endregion

       #region ShipDate
       [PXDBDate(BqlField = typeof(SOShipment.shipDate))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipment Date")]
       public virtual DateTime? ShipDate { get; set; }
       public abstract class shipDate : IBqlField { }
       #endregion

       #region CustomerID
       [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(SOShipment.customerID))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer")]
       [PXSelector(typeof(Customer.bAccountID), new Type[] { typeof(Customer.acctCD), typeof(Customer.acctName) },
           SubstituteKey = typeof(Customer.acctCD), DescriptionField = typeof(BAccount.acctName))]
       public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
       public abstract class customerID : IBqlField { }
       #endregion

       #region Shipped Quantity
       [PXDBDecimal(BqlField = typeof(SOShipment.shipmentQty))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipped Quantity")]
       public virtual decimal? ShipmentQty { get; set; }
       public abstract class shipmentQty : IBqlField { }
       #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you played around with MatrixMode and/or SyncPosition on your page grid? You might need SyncPosition="True"
Also, does the issue occur if not using process all? (process 1 or 2 rows)

Comment: I am facing same issue, After process records, grid records disappear, I have to force refresh to show remain records. SyncPosition="True" set in my grid.

Comment: @Brandan, I was doing mistake, now my issue has been solved, but grid show only processed records, now all records. let say i have selected single records to processed out of 5 then after processing, only processed records are showing, i need to force refresh to show all records, How to show all records as per my filter applied?

Comment: This is how the processing pages work (at the end show the results of what was run). You could try some refresh techniques such as actions press cancel or view refresh after but not sure that would work

Comment: I am facing same issue of disappear, if columns values are coming from join table, Is it necessary to use projection DAC to resolve the issue? Also my Processed dialog not showing vertical scroll and rows are hidden, when i click on refresh then paging appear enabled and rows goes to 2nd page how to resolve this issue?